# KMP String Matching Algorithm stuck in a loop

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I'm trying to implement KMP String Matching Algorithm using CLRS, but with the text input as "bbaa" and pattern input as "aab", it gets stuck in an infinite loop in the `while` loop inside the `getKMPPrefix` function. My code is given below:

```
private int[] getKMPPrefix(char[] p, int m) {
    int[] prefix = new int[m];
    prefix[0] = 0;
    int k = 0;
    for(int q = 1; q < m; q++) {
        while(k > 0 && p[k] != p[q] ) { //Stuck here
            k = prefix[k];
        }
        if(p[k] == p[q]) {
            k++;
        }
        prefix[q] = k;
    }
    return prefix;
}

public void kmp(String text, String pattern) {
    char[] t = text.toCharArray();
    char[] p = pattern.toCharArray();
    int n = text.length();
    int m = pattern.length();

    int[] prefix = getKMPPrefix(p, m);

    int q = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        while(q > 0 && p[q] != t[i]) {
            q = prefix[q];
        }
        if(p[q] == t[i]) {
            q++;
        }
        if(q == m) {
            System.out.println("Pattern occurs with shift " + (i-m+1));
            q = prefix[m-1];
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea why this is the case?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what is happening:

It reaches the line :

```
while(k > 0 && p[k] != p[q] ) { //Stuck here
```

`k=0` so obviously this will fail and it will jump out of the loop and goto next one

```
if(p[k] == p[q]) {
            k++;
        }
```

In you case, the input is `aab` so this is true `p[0]=p[1]=a`

Now, `k=1`

Now you assign `k`'s value to `prefix`

```
prefix[q] = k;
```

Now it runs into deadlock.

It'll go back to `while` loop now

```
 while(k > 0 && p[k] != p[q] ) { //Stuck here
            k = prefix[k];
        }
```

Notice, you just assigned in earlier loop `prefix[q] = k;` i.e `p[1] =  1`

when it comes to `while` loop `k=1` and 'p[1] != p[2]' i.e `a!=b` It passes and goes inside loop

```
k = prefix[k];
```

`k=1` and `prefix[1] = 1`, which mean you are reassigning the value `1` to `k`

It goes back again to while loop and value of `k=1` and `p=1` since it never went past the `while` loop to increment `p`

There is the deadlock, the condition will remain `true` for the `while` loop and the program will never come out of `while` loop.

Either you can change you `while` loops condition or increment `p` inside while loop or `break` inside while after certain condition. I explained the `Deadlock`, try and figure out the program yourself though. Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int[] computPrefix(String P) 
    {
        int m = P.length();
        int[] prefix = new int[m];
        prefix[0]=0; // you just mentioned this
        prefix[1]=0; // mention this in initial condition
        int k = 0;
 // start loop form i = 2. You can find the clear explanation in CLRS page number 1002
        for(int i = 2; i<m; i++)
        {
            while(k>0 && P.charAt(k) != P.charAt(i))
            {
                k = prefix[k]; // NO deadlock
            }

            if(P.charAt(k)==P.charAt(i))
            {
                k++;
            }
            prefix[i] = k;
        }
        return prefix;
    }
```

You code will cause deadlock for example if pattern is "aabaaa". This correct condition will generate prefix in right way.